# what is the best way to import source functions from test

Tags: python

I have a project that contains python scripts
with this hierarchy:
project->main-> src-> python -> 
and test scripts
project-> main-> test->python-> module ->

from the test, I want to call functions from the source folder
the way I find out was to add this in my test script:

```
sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__file__)))))
from main.src.pyhon import X
```

isn't there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Your structure is not clear. Do you have a folder called: "test scripts project -> main -> test" or do you have "test scripts: project -> main -> test". Namely do you have only one "main" folder that has both "src" and "test"?

Comment: @astrochun 
project->main-> src-> python ->
and
project-> main-> test->python-> module ->

Answer (score 0):

when you have this:

```
project
  main
    src
      python
        <python sources>
        source1.py
        ...
        sourceN.py

  test
    python
      module.py
```

and you want to import `stuff` from `python` folder into `unittesting` you have to:

in `module.py` (test/python/module.py)

```py
from project.main.src.python.source1 import <function> or *
...
from project.main.src.python.sourceN import <function> or *

# test your functions
result = function1(param)
print(result)
```

or you can:

```
from main.src.python.source1 import <function> or *
...
from main.src.python.sourceN import <function> or *
```

using this method in a editor such as `vscode` the intellisense `wont work`, then i recommend the first option.

anyway, both methods work when running the code.

Comment: I don't see any `__init__.py` so those import statements will not likely work since the sub-packages will not be indexed

Comment: try it and tell me what happened.

Comment: How did you ensure that `project` is importable? With sys.path or `python setup.py` or some other way?